# where is concourse.ci metadata variable substition happening?

Tags: continuous-integration, concourse

In concourse pipeline definitions you can use metadata variables like `$BUILD_NAME` et.al.

While working on a custom resource, I was wondering where the variable substitution is happening: in the yml or in the resource scripts?

To me it seems as if the variables are **not** substituted in the yml before passing to scripts and scripts have to take care of that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, metadata variable substitution is done in the resource scripts.

A container, particularly a resource `get` or `put` container is two things: a root filesystem and a running process (of the script `/opt/resource/get` or `/opt/resource/put`). The [metadata variables](http://concourse.ci/implementing-resources.html#resource-metadata) are environment variables that are set on that running process. The metadata variable strings (e.g. `$BUILD_NAME`) are just passed as is through the templating process to the resource. It's the responsibility of the resource to look for those strings and substitute them with the appropriate environment variables.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. my problem was that I passed the strings into JSON via `jq` and therefore the auto-expansion / substitution of environment variables in bash scripts didnt work. so I had to force it like `name=$(echo "$params"| jq -r '.params.name')  name=$(eval echo $name)`

Comment: @pHiL, FYI, the better-practice way to change `varname=foo` to the contents of `$foo` is to use `${!varname}`; this avoids the ability to run arbitrary code present with `eval`. Granted, in this case,  you'd need to use `varname=${varname#'$'}` first to strip the leading `$`.